# Highlight cells in two CollectionView

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I use two `CollectionView` in one `ViewController`. Each `CollectionView` has 5 cells. I also use `isSelected` to detect selected cell (and highlight selected cell) for each `CollectionView`. In each `CollectionView`, only one cell can be selected (highlighted).

Everything works as it should, but there is one problem.

In simulator, when I select a cell with an index from 0 to 3, everything works fine. But the problem becomes when I select a cell with index 4. This highlights cells with index 4 in both `CollectionView`.

This only happens when the cell with index 4 of another `CollectionView` is not visible on the screen (I use the horizontal scrolling for both collection views and only 3 of 5 cells are visible at one time on the screen).

Below the part of my code:

```
var selectIndex = 1

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    if collectionView == self.percentsCollectionView {
        let cell:PercentCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: percentsCellIdentifiers[indexPath.item], for: indexPath) as! PercentCollectionViewCell

        if selectIndex == (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row
        {
            cell.isSelected = true
        }
        else
        {
            cell.isSelected = false
        }
        return cell
    }

    else {
        let cell:PersonCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: personsCellIdentifiers[indexPath.item], for: indexPath) as! PersonCollectionViewCell

        if selectIndex == (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row
        {
            cell.isSelected = true
        }
        else
        {
            cell.isSelected = false
        }
        return cell
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    selectIndex = (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row
    collectionView.reloadData()
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`selectIndex = (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row
collectionView.reloadData()`

this part doesn't exactly says which collection view to select. its just the index and both collection view will get selected. The only reason you don't see this for 0-3 is that you are not reloading the other collection view. but the 4th index has to reload (when you scroll to see it) and it will get selected.

you have to use 2 different indexes for each collection view

eg:

`selectIndex1` and `selectIndex2`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to use two different indexes. I have created selectPercentIndex and selectPersonIndex. I do not quite understand how I should reloading other collectionview now.

Comment: `collectionView1.reloadData()` and `collectionView2.reloadData()`. you can see what you are missing. use two indexes and use proper index value in `cellForItemAt ` method.